# Make a field optional in Kotlinx serialization

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parsing, kotlinx.serialization

Here is my pojo class

```
@Serializable
data class Response(
    @SerialName("message") val message: String?,
    @SerialName("parameters") val parameters: Map<String, String>?
)
```

And this is Json, I was trying to decode from:

```
{
   "message": "Some text"
}
```

Here, the field `parameters` is optional. When I try to decode like

```
Json.decodeFromString<Response>(response)
```

I am getting the following exception:

> kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Field 'parameters' is
> required for type with serial name 'Response', but it was missing

I was looking forward to set the field `parameters` to `null`, if the field is missing in the `Json`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to specify a default value for your `parameters` property like this:

```
@Serializable
data class Response(
    @SerialName("message") val message: String?,
    @SerialName("parameters") val parameters: Map<String, String>? = null
)
```

You can read more about this here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#optional-properties